# How to use google database to create any mobile application?

Tags: java, iphone, asp.net, android

I m going to develope an application in which i m not using inbuilt database as well as Web Services.
I Want to use google database..means if my user want to search for some query.i must pass that question to google and behalf of google result,i'll display resule to client in my application.e.g in listview.

can anyone tell me how can i do that..??

Comment: First of all you have to crawl the internet and put this into your OWN database. Then you can query the whole time and what you like.

Comment: Hi could you clarify what you mean by "google database" i found this interesting but after, err googling i couldn't find any details on this

Comment: dear..first of all thanks for your response.i want to say that i want to use google's search result as adatabase....suppose my application is for seach restaurant by city..when i get any city from user...by coding i'll search in google..and behalf of google's result ..i'll display list of restaurant in that city..dear can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consude Google Custom search API based on JSON/Atom. You can programs to retrieve and display search results from Google Custom Search programmatically.

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Comment: Read its section "Programmatically Creating Custom Search Engines" http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/api.html